# Destructuring assignment for nested properties

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I need to get 3 variables `cx`,`cx` and `weatherIcon` from an object `this.props.payload` currently I am using this code

```
const { cx, cy } = this.props
const {weatherIcon} = this.props.payload
```

It works, but I would like to know if it is possible to write in a single line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
const { cx, cy, payload: { weatherIcon } } = this.props;
```

```js
const props = { cx: 1, cy: 2, payload: { weatherIcon: 3 }};
const { cx, cy, payload: { weatherIcon } } = props;
console.log(cx, cy, weatherIcon);
```